# How to merge two lists while adding metadata indicating value source with LINQ statement?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

Given, for instance:

```
var a = new List<int>(){ 1 , 2 , 50 };
var b = new List<int>(){ 9 , 7 , 2 };
```

I need to merge them together to one sorted list, while adding some data indicating their origin (`a` or `b`). An output for example would be something like:

```
mergedList = { {1,false},{2,false},{2,true},{7,true},{9,true},{50,false} }
```

(`true` means it comes from `a`).

### Edit start...

```
mergedList =
{ {1,IsB=false},{2,IsB=false},{2,IsB=true},{7,IsB=true},{9,IsB=true},{50,IsB=false} }
```

### ...Edit end

How can I do it with `LINQ`, preferably in query statement form (`from ... select ...`) ?

Comment: _"true means it comes from a"_ is not what your desired result suggests.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: correct. I fixed it in my edit..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var aItems = from aa in a
             select new {Value = aa, Indicator = true};
var bItems = from bb in b
             select new {Value = bb, Indicator = false};

var result = aItems.Concat(bItems).OrderBy(t => t.Value);
```

And pure method syntax:

```
var aItems = a.Select(aa => new {Value = aa, Indicator = true});
var bItems = b.Select(bb => new {Value = bb, Indicator = false});
var result = aItems.Concat(bItems).OrderBy(t => t.Value);
```

Comment: You are missing the ordering. Furthermore, this code shows when *not* to use the query syntax, because it makes the resulting code unreadable.

Comment: Now it's readable but it's a mixture of query- and method-syntax. @Tal: Get used to method-syntax in C#.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Thank you. I added method-syntax too. I leaved the query-syntax due to the question where is written: _preferably in query statement form (from ... select ...)_

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: I've removed obfuscation. Hope it's legit now.

Answer (score 4):

Not query form, but should work.

```
var ans = a.Select(i => new { Value = i, FromA = true })
           .Concat(b.Select(i => new { Value = i, FromA = false }))
           .OrderBy(i => i.Value);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create an anonymous type with the additional property:

```
var a = new List<int>(){ 1 , 2 , 50 };
var b = new List<int>(){ 9 , 7 , 2 };
var ax = a.Select(i => new{ Num = i, FromB = false });
var bx = b.Select(i => new{ Num = i, FromB = true});

var merged = ax.Concat(bx).OrderBy(x => x.Num);
```

Note that `Enumerable.Concat` will not eliminate dulicates, but since you want to add the origin i assume that this is desired.

Output:

```
foreach(var x in merged)
    Console.WriteLine("Num: {0} From-B? {1}", x.Num, x.FromB);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/t2MzlX)

Comment: He wanted the `bool` to be true if it was from `a` and he wanted the results ordered by the `int` value.

Comment: @juharr: But the desired result suggests that it should be true when it's from _b_. However, i assume that he understands the logic.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with anonymous types:

```
var mergedList = a.Select(x => new {val = x, tag = true})
                  .Union(b.Select(x => new {val = x, tag = false}))
                  .OrderBy(x => x.val);
```